CSV Lint new user
Being new using CSV Lint
Not sure how to configure the plugin.
I have a CSV with text in " " between each coma (,)
When I reformat and align the columns the quote get removed and do not seem to  get them back
Here a sample of two line
"US","","CA","","","","","false","","","","","false"
"CA","","","","Product Delivery - DVD;Co-Administrator;Account Admin;Download SDKs and APIs;Download;License Manager;License Manager - Home use;Download Technical Previews","false","","","","","false"

Not sure what to do, looking for some advice

Hi . A field needs to be quoted when its value contains a character that actually makes up the encoding, like the comma. The comma (usually) denotes the ending of one field and the beginning of another. If a field's value has a comma itself, like Last, First, then the comma must be quoted, like "Last, First", so the CSV readers only see the one value Last, First. Some CSV writers quote everything, even when no special character needs to be quoted. Maybe CSV Lint is removing unnecessary quotes.

If you add a comma somewhere, make sure it's quoted, like "US,", and then save/lint the file, what happens? Are quotes saved? Then, remove the comma, back to "US", and save/lint... quotes disappear?

Thank you for the feedback
However I was looking at: when  CSVLInt align the colums under Notepad++, it remove the quote. How can we have CSVLint to align the column while keeping the quote?
Once we finish edit the CSV, how can we bring back the file by removing the column alignment keep the quote so the CSV file can be reuse to import data to the original system?

Plugin developer here. In the Reformat dialog there is a drop down list "Re-apply quotes". It indicates how quotes are applied. The options are None, Values with Spaces, All Strings, All Non-numerics, All Values. Sounds like you're looking for the option All Values. This dropdown was added in v0.4.6.3 april 2023, so if you don't see it then update to the latest version.
